# can someone show me an example of magento2 payment response json?

Tags: json, magento, payment, magento2, gateway

We are creating our own payment gateway, however we cant find out how Magento handles the response.

We are looking for samples in order to capture and authorize payments in  our website.

I have already created admin section, form.

Can someone please show an example of the response?

Thanks

Comment: what extract .. your requirement and what is the follow of payment gateway

Comment: I've been reading a lot and cant find out how Magento2 works payment gateway related.

Comment: Can you develop a payment gateway for us?